# Calculate word frequencies from text file, But there is an error in my output

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-analysis

Read all the lines from the file and split the lines into words using the split() method. Further, remove punctuation from the ends of words using the `strip("""!"#$%&'()*,-./:;?@[]_""")` method call

I am very beginner in python and trying to solve some basic problems, I have used split and strip function in the problem given but I am getting the error in frequencies of some words, please review my code.

**Python Code:**

```
def word_frequencies(filename="alice.txt"):

    with open(filename) as f:
        string=f.read()

    words=string.split()

    l=[]

    for word in words:
        temp=word.strip("""!"#$%&'()*,-./:;?@[]""")

        if temp:
            l.append(temp)


    string2=[]

    for i in l:
        if i not in string2:
            string2.append(i)

    for j in string2:
        print(f"{j}\t{l.count(j)}")
```

**Output:**

```
The 64 

Project 83

Gutenberg   27

EBook   3

of  303
```

.
.
.
and so on.

**But the actual output is:**

```
The     64

Project 83

Gutenberg   26

EBook   3

of      303
```

.
.
.
and so on

Comment: can you share your input file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AjbDhSLpdJTDR7IIeXZj28LyQPHGOJBK/view?usp=sharing It is there on drive

Answer (score 1):

Use *re.findall* to split up to words:

```
from re import findall

words = findall(r"\b\w+\b", text)
```

, where *text* is your *f.read()*.

Then count them:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(words)
```

Check word count:

```
for word in ("The", "Project", "Gutenberg", "EBook",):
    print(word, c[word])
```

Prints:

```
The 64
Project 83
Gutenberg 83
EBook 3
```

Comment: Thanks, Arsegg, But the output is incorrect. I have mentioned the correct output. Please check it out.